# Tail multiple logfiles using glogg

Tags: ubuntu, logging, monitoring

I am working on the backend as well as the frontend of an application and I need to be able to tail log files for multiple processes (at least two).

glogg is the log viewer I'm using at the moment and I'm very happy with it, apart from the fact that I can't get it to view / tail multiple files at once.

Does anyone know how to get this to work? Or know a workaround?

I'm developing on an Ubuntu system.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple workaround is to start glogg via the command-line. Unity finds it already running and directs you to the running instance.

Comment: Should've thought of that! Thanks!